# Facebook OG not picking up nodejs - handlebars data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, handlebars.js

I understand that since the data is dynamically loaded on the page with handlebars from nodejs that Facebook crawlers do not pick it up... however, how do I allow them to see what it is or send them an update or something...

This is my current facebook og example:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="{{project.description}}" />
```

And it shows text from the root url website instead, it was working in the past so not sure what happen that all of a sudden Facebook is not retrieving the data?

Here is a test link:

http://www.liovinci.com/i/ara

Comment: a testlink would be a good idea...

Comment: http://www.liovinci.com/i/ara  --- I added it above as well thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the current `og:url` tag: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://liovinci.com/i/" />`

As you can see, it does not link to your current URL, so it will take the OG data from the URL specified in the `og:url` - which redirects to the root URL.

Change the `og:url` tag to the following: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://liovinci.com/i/ara" />`

Comment: It is dynamic though it looks like this "<meta property="og:url" content="http://liovinci.com/i/{{project.url}}" />"

Comment: not sure what you mean, that´s what the sourcecode tells me ;) - and that´s definitely the issue.

Comment: Sounds good, yep had an issue with what was being passed back